# System Drivers on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I want to ask a question I am a new user to Ubuntu and I am    going to install it on my PC and Remove Windows as I have read a lot    about Ubuntu and how it's solid based system and that it's more    stable and stronger but to be honest I am a bit afraid of installing    it as I don't have the drivers CD so Does Ubuntu need drivers or not    ? and how do I check that all the drivers are installed and updated    and work correctly ? and If I want to install a driver will Ubuntu    help me to search for it and install it ? 
and will Ubuntu install the sound card . the internet card and the graphics etc. automatically or not waiting for your replies    cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you burn the ubuntu live cd to disc you will see what works as you can use it from the cd or usb. Use this to try sound and wifi. Your hdd and dvd drives etc can also be tested.
The only thing I need drivers for is my graphics card and they are provided in system setting / proprietary drivers. 
If some thing doesnt work on the live cd it wont work when installed. Personally I have had 100 percent hardware compatability with ubuntu.
Hope I helped

Comment: This is a good answer, it will allow you to test your system, but don't judge the speed of the OS by the Live CD, everything you run will have to load into you memory off the CD so it will run sluggishly.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the Ubuntu certified hardware [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/).

As stated before, trying out a Live CD or USB before you install it can also be useful.